# Class instance that returns a mock during tests and real implementation during normal run

Tags: .net, tdd, mocking

Title pretty much says what I'm asking but I'll just explain what I'm after.

I've been reading up on Unit Testing lately but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around mocks. and especially the mocking of objects that involve the system / system's resources.

Say you have class that needs to interact with a network.

From what I've read around on Unit Testing within .NET, the pattern is to basically create a wrapper object around classes that interact with the network. And pass an interface of that object (through a constructor for example) to your logic class. Then during tests you could substitute that wrapper class with a mock one.

Now sometimes, a class is basic enough that it does not and should not accept weird adapters or wrappers through its constructor or setter functions.

It's basically making your code more complex by having each of your classes accept the classes it depends on in order to achieve unit testing.

So my question is simply this, is there some sort of mechanism that during instancing of an object returns the real one - if it's a normal run, and a mock one - if it's a test run.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have a class that does a lot of file system operations, and you want to be able to test your class without worrying about reading/writing files to a real file system.

You create an interface, similar to below:

```
public interface IFileSystem
{
    bool FileExists(string filePath);
    string[] ReadAllLines(string filePath);
    //...more methods as appropriate
}
```

and implement the interface on a wrapper class:

```
public class RealFileSystem : IFileSystem
{
    public bool FileExists(string filePath)
    {
        return File.Exists(filePath);
    }

    public string[] ReadAllLines(string filePath)
    {
        return File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
    }
}
```

Then, with your file system manipulation class, you'd instantiate it using *dependency injection*:

```
public class ClassThatDoesFileSystemStuff
{
    private readonly IFileSystem fileSystem;
    public ClassThatDoesFileSystemStuff(IFileSystem fs)
    {
        this.fileSystem = fs;
    }

    public ClassThatDoesFileSystemStuff() : this(new RealFileSystem())
    {
    }

    public void DoSomeStuff()
    {
        string path = @"C:\temp.txt";
        if (fileSystem.FileExists(path))
        {
            fileSystem.ReadAllLines(path);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the class above has two constructors: One which takes an instance of a class implementing IFileSystem, and one that doesn't. The one that doesn't calls the one that does, instantiating a new `RealFileSystem` to use during the lifetime of the class.

Then, for unit testing, you can inject a mock of IFileSystem into that class. You can use a mocking framework like RhinoMocks or Moq, or you can just roll your own:

```
public class FakeFileSystem : IFileSystem
{
    public bool FileExists(string filePath)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public string[] ReadAllLines(string filePath)
    {
        return new[] {"This", "is", "a", "bunch of", "text!"};
    }
}
```

And during your test, do

```
var objectToTest = new ClassThatDoesFileSystemStuff(new FakeFileSystem());
```

The important thing to realize is that you're loosely coupling your classes. You don't *want* the class to know what type of IFileSystem to use. You want to *tell* the class what implementation of IFileSystem to use.

Comment: +1 for a nice example! My only quibble is with the two constructors - I'd go with a DI Container framework rather than Poor Man's DI. I'm guessing you didn't want to complicate the example.

Comment: @TrueWill Correct! I love me some Ninject :)

Comment: @TrueWill I love me some Poor Man's DI. :-) Ninject is one of the better DI containers, but I sometimes wonder if it's really all that necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial explanation is correct. You're on the right track.

Usually if a class is **so** basic that there's no need for dependencies (and that's probably more basic than you think), it doesn't have any behavior worth testing. It's an adapter - you hang an interface off it and inject it as a dependency into something else.

You certainly **can** return a fake implementation from a class given a particular state, but if you're going to that much trouble, it's probably easier to have two implementations, an interface, and a constructor parameter.

In any case I try to avoid referencing mocking libraries (AKA isolation frameworks) in production code. I only reference those in test code. If you want to return a fake from a non-test class, I'd write the implementation.